# Two panel actitivity for tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

final question on this project I hope. I am trying to get a layout that is different for tablets and phones. I thought I had it all correct but it only shows the phone layout on a tablet when tested.

here is the java for the activity

```
package jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.hw2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class ListActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private int is_phone = 0;

protected int getLayoutResId(){
    return R.layout.activity_masterdetail;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResId());

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        is_phone = 1;

        ListFragment listfrag = new ListFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, 
listfrag).commit();
    }
}

public int getIs_phone(){

    return is_phone;
}
}
```

After that this is the xml for the phone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And the xml for the two panel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_cont"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the refs.xml for no smaller width than 600dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="activity_masterdetail" 
type="layout">@layout/activity_twopane</item>
</resources>
```

And the ref.xml for everything else

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="activity_masterdetail" 
type="layout">@layout/activity_list</item>
</resources>
```

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: This use of ref.xml looks a little complicated to me. Why don't you use different layout folders (res/layout and res/layout-sw600dp) and put one layout file in each of the folders? (the files must have the same name and the file content would be once the phone screen and once the tablet screen)

Comment: Messing around and changing the width to 0dp on the fragments on the two panel seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: I was wondering so much about the ref.xml, I never looked into the layout files, sorry. Good you managed to fix it. BTW do you know LayoutInspector? In AndroidStudio, click on Tools -> Android -> LayoutInspector. Great tool if you're wondering where your Views have gone.